# Is it possible for multiple processes to simultaneously only read (not write to) from a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have spawned multiple processes using multiprocessing.Process in a loop and each process is trying to read the same file. Will this cause an issue ? References to the answers are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

It's no problem. Not only applies to files, also to RAM. You only get in trouble when someone is writing.

The phenomenon is called a [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race) (emphasis mine):

> **access** [==read] a memory location at the same time that a memory operation in another thread is **writing** to that memory location